# Add product variation with subscription plan in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, subscription

I want to add product variation in such a way that , On product details page , user will see 2 types of plan LIKE Single & Subscription.

In single plan , user can buy a single bottle and proceed.

In subscription , we provide say 3 bottles together with some reduced price and also allow user to continue subscription for 1 year or for unlimited time.

So that when he buys subscription in background , will have to do renewal of subscription and also automatic payment.

so back to my questions , like its easy to add variations like different colour and sizes.. but how to achieve in my above case.

I have also bought WooCommerce Subscription plugin.

I am very new to wordpress , so need some guidelines , is this possible or not , if yes what approach should i take? can we add variations like single and subscription for the same product.

Thanks in advance.